# How to see all the available Python pip/Conda packages that are available for particular jupyter kernel?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have the same problem as https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2359 - my jupyter kernel does not see the installed package and is not importing it. How can I see the list of packages that are available for particular kernel?

Comment: Are you sure that the kernel you are running really is the Conda env that you installed the package in?  Could you show us the result of `!conda info` from in the notebook?